# how to detect redirects of url occurs while loading UIWebView on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, redirect, uiwebview

Is there any way to detect url redirects occurs while loading a UIWebView in iphone. when I load www.example.com url, it redirects to some other url. I need to get those redirecting urls and where is actually we handles redirection.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do this. Implement

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

This [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) . This method gets called whenever your webview is about to make a request. So now when someone clicks a button or hyperlink on your webpage, you will get a call to this method. After you catch this call, you can choose to do whatever you want with it. Like redirect the link through your own servers, or log a request to your server about user activity or in your case bring up comments page or change nav bar etc.

Maybe from the `request` you can figure out if the HTTP response code is 3xx redirection then you can do what you want...

Comment: so, how will i get the redirected URL?

Comment: or, is their any way to find which redirection get failed. actually my web url redirect two times. if first redirect goes faild i need to do some actions. is their any way?

Comment: how to figure out the responsecode from the request itself?

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread when having to do the same.  I used Srikar's answer, but here is my code.

I'm using Lumberjack logging, but you can replace the below with just NSLog.  You can also get specific parts of the URL if you were looking at host, path, or query string to know if there is a failure (which is what I'm about to have to do).  If it redirects several times, each request will get called here and if you want you can stop it and do something or just observe.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Redirecting to URL: %@", inRequest.URL.absoluteString);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
        if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ){
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
       return YES;
    }
```

Comment: actually the site automatically redirects to another webUrl